# Can sums be manipulated in this way?

Tags: summation, induction

I'm working on an induction proof and I'm trying to manipulate a sum so that I can use my inductive hypothesis. Is the following possible?

$$\sum_{i=1}^{3n+4} i = \sum_{i=1}^{3n+1+3}i = \sum_{i=1}^{3n+1}i + \sum_{i=3n+2}^{3n+4}i$$

Comment: Sure!  Well, you term x doesn't seem to have anything to do with i but of course you can do that.

Comment: yes, why would you think not? you are just regroupong summands

Comment: Thanks, both. I only thought not because I haven't seen that before. As for the second term, could I change that to (3n+2) + (3n+3) + (3n+4)? Or is there a problem because the n is being multiplied by a coefficient > 1?

Comment: @playitright Yes, you can do that.
$\sum\limits_{i=a_n}^{a_m} i = a_n + \dots + a_m$ for $m \geq n$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course. Even more generally, using a generic summand, you're just saying
$$a_1+\cdots+a_{k+n}=(a_1+\cdots+a_k)+(a_{k+1}+\cdots+a_{k+n})$$